# Use Restangular with custom RubyOnRails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular

On my `rails` app, I have the following route:

`POST   /api/patients/:id/update_weights(.:format)   api/patients#update_weights {:format=>:json}`

I'd like to `post` data from my `angular` app to my `rails` app so as `update_weights` action triggers. I would like to send the following data:
 `{"param1" : "value", "param2" : "value", "param3" : "value"}`

Does anyone know how to do this with `Restangular`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I used:

```
update: (id, param1, param2, param3) ->
  Restangular.one("patients", id)
             .post("update_weights" ,{param_1: param1, param_2: param2, param_3: param3})
```

Comment: Good find. Why wouldn't this work with `.put('update_weights', {...})`? I'm so confused with Restangular